# SQL: Get row number which increases every time a value changes

Tags: sql, partition, vertica

I have the following table in Vertica:

```
+----------+----------+----------+
| column_1 | column_2 | column_3 |
+----------+----------+----------+
| a        |        1 |        1 |
| a        |        2 |        1 |
| a        |        3 |        1 |
| b        |        1 |        1 |
| b        |        2 |        1 |
| b        |        3 |        1 |
| c        |        1 |        1 |
| c        |        2 |        1 |
| c        |        3 |        1 |
| c        |        1 |        2 |
| c        |        2 |        2 |
| c        |        3 |        2 |
+----------+----------+----------+
```

The table is ordered by column_1 and column_3.
I would like to add a row number, which increases every time when column_1 or column_3 change their value. It would look something like this:

```
+----------+----------+----------+------------+
| column_1 | column_2 | column_3 | row_number |
+----------+----------+----------+------------+
| a        |        1 |        1 |          1 |
| a        |        2 |        1 |          1 |
| a        |        3 |        1 |          1 |
| b        |        1 |        1 |          2 |
| b        |        2 |        1 |          2 |
| b        |        3 |        1 |          2 |
| c        |        1 |        1 |          3 |
| c        |        2 |        1 |          3 |
| c        |        3 |        1 |          3 |
| c        |        1 |        2 |          4 |
| c        |        2 |        2 |          4 |
| c        |        3 |        2 |          4 |
+----------+----------+----------+------------+
```

I tried using partition over but I can't find the right syntax.

Comment: How is the table ordered? Is it by the values in column_1 and column_3?

Comment: Yes. The table is ordered by column_1 and column_3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vertica has the `CONDITIONAL_CHANGE_EVENT()` analytic functions.
It starts at 0, and increments by 1 every time the expression that makes the first argument undergoes a change.

Like so:

```
WITH
indata(column_1,column_2,column_3,rn) AS (
          SELECT 'a',1,1,1
UNION ALL SELECT 'a',2,1,1
UNION ALL SELECT 'a',3,1,1
UNION ALL SELECT 'b',1,1,2
UNION ALL SELECT 'b',2,1,2
UNION ALL SELECT 'b',3,1,2
UNION ALL SELECT 'c',1,1,3
UNION ALL SELECT 'c',2,1,3
UNION ALL SELECT 'c',3,1,3
UNION ALL SELECT 'c',1,2,4
UNION ALL SELECT 'c',2,2,4
UNION ALL SELECT 'c',3,2,4
)
SELECT
  *
, CONDITIONAL_CHANGE_EVENT(
  column_1||column_3::VARCHAR
  ) OVER w + 1 AS rownum
FROM indata
WINDOW w AS (ORDER BY column_1,column_3,column_2)
;
-- out  column_1 | column_2 | column_3 | rn | rownum 
-- out ----------+----------+----------+----+--------
-- out  a        |        1 |        1 |  1 |      1
-- out  a        |        2 |        1 |  1 |      1
-- out  a        |        3 |        1 |  1 |      1
-- out  b        |        1 |        1 |  2 |      2
-- out  b        |        2 |        1 |  2 |      2
-- out  b        |        3 |        1 |  2 |      2
-- out  c        |        1 |        1 |  3 |      3
-- out  c        |        2 |        1 |  3 |      3
-- out  c        |        3 |        1 |  3 |      3
-- out  c        |        1 |        2 |  4 |      4
-- out  c        |        2 |        2 |  4 |      4
-- out  c        |        3 |        2 |  4 |      4
```

Comment: I was looking at this function, but the help text was to hard for me to understand. You made it very clear how it works. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In the absence of an `ORDER BY`, SQL data sets are unordered.  To establish the order in your example therefore, I've assumed the dataset can be sorted with `ORDER BY column_1, column_3, column_2`

- If that assumption doesn't work, you MUST add additional columns that the data can be deterministically sorted by.

That gives the following query...

```
SELECT
  yourTable.*,
  DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY column_1, column_3) AS row_number
FROM
  yourTable
ORDER BY
  column_1, column_3, column_2
```

Comment: This won't work. My first intuition was to use dense_rank as well.

Answer (score 1):

This would also work and doesn't require table sorting

1. Find distinct value from column_1 and column_3 and give new index for them
2. Merge the previous with origin table on column_1 and column_3

```sql
select t1.*, t2.row_number 
from
your_table t1
join 
(select column_1, column_2, row_number() over (partition by temp) as row_number from (select distinct column_1, column_2, 1 as temp from your_table) foo) t2
on
t1.column_1=t2.column_1 and t1.column_2=t2.column_2;
```